# I have no power in my attic and there are not any tripped breakers of GFCI in the house

Tags: wiring, attic

In my Attic I a have  an outlet, junction box that goes to Two ceiling Fans that are not working and a pull string mounted light.I used a voltage tester one all three(outlet, junction box, and light) there is no power to any of them.
Can any one help troubleshoot for me?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! We're going to need a lot more information in order to help. First, how long has this been going on, and was there anything done to those (or any other) circuits recently? Are there any GFCI receptacles that are tripped? Have you reset (turned off and then back on) the breaker for this circuit? Are there any switches in the attic that those fixtures may be tied in to, and if so, are they on?

Comment: Thanks you getting back to me . I have reset all the breakers and GFCI This happened a few week ago were the ceiling fans didn't work for a few days but then came back on. they have a remote they are not tied into a switch. The junction box in the attic is tied to the ceiling fans. The outlet goes into the junction box as well as the light. I haven't been able to tract which circuit they are on because they are at the end of the trail. My thought was the the wiring comes up into the outlet first then to the junction box. If the outlet is shorted out wouldn't that cause the rest to not work?

Comment: If the outlet is shorted, then the breaker should have tripped

Comment: I thought is should I just cant figure out why there is no power I check all other outlets all are working fine. This outlet must be close to the end of the circuit. so it is cutting power to the junction box, that provides power to the ceiling fans and the  pull string light in the attic. The outlet in attic is back stabbed. if that is loose would it cause no power to go to the outlet, and not cause any breaker to trip?

Comment: Yes, a loose or open backstabbed connection would break the circuit. Switch off the breaker and change the backstabbed wire to the side screw and tighten firmly. Make sure the side tab is not broken off.

Answer (score 1):

Most circuits are wired as strings, from outlet to outlet to outlet in a line.  (An *outlet* is a receptacle or a hardwired load).  Sometimes they are wired in a tee or tree arrangement, but the same basic idea applies.

Let's say the circuit is a string, PANEL - V - W - X -  Y - Z.

Let's say X and everything past it (Y and Z) lose power, and W is the last outlet that is still good.  It is usually a faulty wire termination or damaged device at X or W.

People often overlook the importance of the location before, W.